# Showing that $\lim_{Q\to\infty}\frac{1}{Q^2}\sum_{n=1}^{Q}\sum_{k=1}^Q \mu(n)\mu(k)\gcd(n,k)=0$ and a twin identity

Tags: number-theory

Recently I have been working with the mobius function, and I stumbled about a pair of very nice identities that I would like to see proved. The first (and main) one is the identity

\begin{equation}\lim_{Q\to\infty}\frac{1}{Q^2}\sum_{n=1}^{Q}\sum_{k=1}^Q \mu(n)\mu(k)\gcd(n,k)=0\tag{1}\end{equation}

where $\mu(n)$ is the Mobius function, and the second very related identity is showing that

\begin{equation}\sum_{n=1}^{Q}\sum_{k=1}^Q \frac{\mu(n)\mu(k)}{\mathrm{lcm}(n,k)}=O_{Q\to\infty}(1)\tag{2}\end{equation}

The motivation behind these questions are relatively straightforward. It is commonly believed that there is a sort of "Mobius pseudo-randomness principle" which states that the assignment of $\mu(n)$ to $\pm1$ is essentially random. A good measure of this would be showing that $\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)$ not only cancels when all terms are included, but also in it's truncated form
$\sum_{d|n \,d<Q}\mu(d)$ as well.

We can see using manipulations that

$$\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\left(\sum_{\substack{d|n \\d<Q}}\mu(d)\right)^2\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{Q-1}\sum_{k=1}^{Q-1} \frac{\mu(n)\mu(k)}{\mathrm{lcm}(n,k)}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{Q}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\left(\sum_{\substack{d|n \\d<Q}}d\mu(d)\right)^2\right]}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{Q^2}\sum_{n=1}^{Q-1}\sum_{k=1}^{Q-1} \mu(n)\mu(k)\gcd(n,k)}$$

this means that getting these two identities which do not seem too hard to prove (especially the first) would help us justify the belief that the Mobius function is near pseudo-random.

EDIT:

I think that an avenue towards proving the first identity would be getting estimates on the single variable sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^Q\mu(k)\gcd(n,k)$$

for some fixed $n$, possibly in the form

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^Q\mu(k)\gcd(n,k)\right|=O_{Q\to\infty, n
\to
\infty}\left(\log(n)Q^{1-\epsilon}\right)$$

which would be enough to establish the identity. Does anyone know of any such results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^Q\sum_{k=1}^Q\mu(n)\mu(k)\gcd(n,k)=S_{\mu}(Q),\quad\sum_{n=1}^Q\sum_{k=1}^Q\frac{\mu(n)\mu(k)}{\operatorname{lcm}(n,k)}=S_{\eta}(Q),$$ where $\eta(n):=\mu(n)/n$, and for any $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, $$S_f(n):=\sum_{a=1}^{n}\sum_{b=1}^{n}f(a)f(b)\gcd(a,b)=\color{blue}{\sum_{a=1}^{n}\varphi(a)F_f(n,a)},\\F_f(n,a):=G_f(\lfloor n/a\rfloor,a)^2,\qquad G_f(n,a):=\sum_{b=1}^{n}f(ab),$$ where $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function); for a proof, we rewrite the LHS as $$S_f(n)=\sum_{d=1}^{n}dS_f(n,d),\quad S_f(n,d):=\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant a,b\leqslant n\\\gcd(a,b)=d}}f(a)f(b),$$
and see that $$\sum_{k\geqslant 1}S_f(n,kd)=\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant a,b\leqslant n\\d\,\mid\,\gcd(a,b)}}f(a)f(b)=\Bigg(\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant a\leqslant n\\d\,\mid\,a}}f(a)\Bigg)^2=F_f(n,d);$$ now [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) gives $S_f(n,d)=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\mu(k)F_f(n,kd)$, and we're done: $$S_f(n)=\sum_{d=1}^{n}d\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\mu(k)F_f(n,kd)=\sum_{a=1}^{n}F_f(n,a)\sum_{d\,\mid\,a}d\mu(a/d)=\sum_{a=1}^{n}F_f(n,a)\varphi(a).$$

---

Now, to prove the **boundedness** of $S_\mu(n)/n^2$ and $S_\eta(n)$, we need good enough estimates of $G_\mu$ and $G_\eta$. Note that $G_\mu(n,1)$ is the [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function), so these are not too easy to get (if we don't assume RH). One can show that $$G_\mu(n,a)=\mu(a)nR_\mu(n,a),\qquad G_\eta(n,a)=\frac{\mu(a)}{a}R_\eta(n,a),$$ and there exist constants $A,B$ such that $|R_{[\mu,\eta]}(n,a)|\leqslant Ae^{-B\sqrt{\log n}}$ (I've outlined the approach in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3775706)). This way, both $S_\mu(n)/n^2$ and $S_\eta(n)$ are bounded above by $A\sum_{a=1}^n a^{-1}e^{-B\sqrt{\log(n/a)}}$, which is bounded w.r.t. $n$ (consider the sum over $n/2^k<a\leqslant 2n/2^k$ over $k>0$).

---

Note also that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}S_\mu(n)/n^2$ is **nonzero**. This can be seen as follows. If $a>n/2$, then $F_\mu(n,a)=|\mu(a)|$, thus $S_\mu(n)\geqslant\kappa(n)-\kappa(n/2)$ where $\kappa(x)=\sum_{n\leqslant x}\varphi(n)|\mu(n)|$ (one gets even better estimates by considering $a>n/3$, $a>n/4$, etc. but this is increasingly complicated). Now $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\varphi(n)|\mu(n)|}{n^s}=\prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\left(1+\frac{p-1}{p^s}\right)=\zeta(s-1)Z(s)$$ with $Z(s)$ regular on $\Re s>3/2$, hence Perron's formula gives (a *nonzero* result) $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\kappa(x)}{x^2}=\frac{Z(2)}{2}=\frac12\prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\left(1-\frac{2}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p^3}\right)\color{LightGray}{\approx 0.21412475283854722\ldots}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I look forward to seeing the proofs! (+1)

Comment: What is the value of the limit of (2)?

Comment: I found an alternate proof that $\liminf >0$ for (1) which is fairly simple. The result that would interest me the most (as discussed in my answer below) would be showing that $\limsup<\infty$ in (2)

Comment: @MiloMoses: I've edited the answer (and removed the claim that the limits exist; this seems likely, but must be much harder to prove, if at all possible). Regarding your alternate proof - I think it's worth posting (somewhere ;).

Comment: Can you include a full proof of your estimates for $\R_{\eta}$ and $R_{\mu}$? This looks fascinating and I would love to see the details of how the computations work out. If it's too much to put on SE then you can just send me a pdf and I'll read that

Comment: Have you finished writing it up yet?

Comment: @MiloMoses: Ready (posted it as another answer).

Comment: Your estimates are proved for $a<n$, which when applied to $F(n,a)$ means that the condition $a<n/a\implies a<\sqrt{n}$. How do you know that the contribution form $a>\sqrt{n}$ is negligible? The estimates can be adapted to get a good result I am sure, but the form you have right now is not a complete proof.

Comment: @MiloMoses: Yes, it looks like I've been in too much hurry prior to my "medical adventures", and now it's time for me to review the linked "answer" completely (at least to try $a\leqslant n^2$, and maybe take a broader look).

Answer (score 1):

This is a supplementary answer with [estimates](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3768842), for integers $0<a\leqslant n$ with $a$ squarefree, of $$R_\mu(n,a):=\frac1n\sum_{b=1}^n\frac{\mu(ab)}{\mu(a)},\qquad R_\eta(n,a):=\sum_{b=1}^n\frac{\mu(ab)}{b\mu(a)}.$$

The summands are multiplicative w.r.t. $b$, and the corresponding Dirichlet series is $$\frac{1}{\zeta_a(s)}:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(an)}{n^s\mu(a)}=\prod_{p\nmid a}(1-p^{-s}).\qquad(\Re s>1)$$

Here we would use [Perron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula) with the shift-the-contour approach (see below) if we could isolate zeros of $\zeta(s)$ from $\Re s=1$ (and a little bit more). If we don't assume RH, the results we have are limited. Say (see section 3.11 of [Titchmarsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Charles_Titchmarsh)'s book on $\zeta$-function),

> There exist positive constants $C_\zeta$, $C_\sigma$, $T_0$ such that, for any $T\geqslant T_0$, we have $$|\zeta(s)|\leqslant C_\zeta\log T,\qquad 1/|\zeta(s)|\leqslant C_\zeta\log T\tag{$\zeta$}\label{zetaest}$$ for any $s=\sigma+it$ with $1-C_\sigma/\log T\leqslant\sigma\leqslant 2$ and $T_0\leqslant|t|\leqslant T$.

*Compare to the case of PNT, when the Dirichlet series is $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$.*

---

So we have to limit the integration in Perron's formula to a finite range, which introduces an error term.

> Suppose that $f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ converges absolutely at $s=\sigma+it$ with $\sigma>\sigma_a\geqslant 0$, and let $g(\sigma)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|n^{-\sigma}$, $\sigma_0>\sigma_a$, $T_0>1$, and $|a_n|\leqslant h(x)$ for $x/2\leqslant n\leqslant 2x$. Then there is a constant $C$ such that, for any $T_0\leqslant T\leqslant x$ and $\sigma_a<\sigma\leqslant\sigma_0$, we have $$\begin{gathered}\sum_{n\leqslant x}a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-iT}^{\sigma+iT}f(s)\frac{x^s}{s}\,ds+\Delta,\\|\Delta|\leqslant C\big(x^\sigma g(\sigma)+xh(x)\log T\big)/T.\end{gathered}\tag{$\smallint$}\label{perrons}$$

The idea for a proof, as well as for Perron's formula itself, is (here $T,y,\sigma>0$) $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-iT}^{\sigma+iT}\frac{y^s}{s}\,ds=I(y)+\Delta',\quad I(y)=\begin{cases}1,&y\leqslant 1,\\0,&y>1\end{cases},\quad|\Delta'|\leqslant y^\sigma\min\left\{1,\frac{1}{\pi T|\log y|}\right\}.$$ (The estimate $|\Delta'|\leqslant y^{\sigma}$ comes from completing the contour by circular arcs, centered at the origin, to the left of $\Re s=\sigma$ if $y\leqslant 1$ and to the right otherwise; the other estimate for $y\neq 1$ is obtained by using rectangular contours instead of circles.)

Now we put $y=x/n$, multiply by $a_n$ and sum over $n$; this gives $$|\Delta|\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^\sigma\min\left\{1,\frac{1}{\pi T|\log(x/n)|}\right\}=\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2,$$ where $\Sigma_1$ is the sum over $n$ with $x/2\leqslant n\leqslant 2x$, and $\Sigma_2$ takes the rest. Further let $\Sigma_1=\Sigma_1^-+\Sigma_1^0+\Sigma_1^+$ with the sums over $x/2\leqslant n\leqslant xe^{-1/\pi T}$, $xe^{-1/\pi T}<n<xe^{1/\pi T}$, and $xe^{1/\pi T}\leqslant n\leqslant 2x$, respectively.

Writing "$A\ll B$" for "there exist a positive constant $C$ such that $A\leqslant CB$", we then have
\begin{align*}
T\Sigma_2&\leqslant\frac{1}{\pi\log 2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^\sigma\ll x^\sigma g(\sigma),
\\T\Sigma_1^0&\ll Th(x)x(e^{1/\pi T}-e^{-1/\pi T})\ll xh(x),\qquad\color{gray}{[\text{we use }x\geqslant T\text{ here!}]}
\\T\Sigma_1^-&\ll h(x)\int_{x/2}^{xe^{-1/\pi T}}\frac{dt}{\log x-\log t}=xh(x)\int_{1/\pi T}^{\log2}\frac{e^{-z}}{z}\,dz\ll xh(x)\log T,
\\T\Sigma_1^+&\ll h(x)\int_{xe^{1/\pi T}}^{2x}\frac{dt}{\log t-\log x}=xh(x)\int_{1/\pi T}^{\log2}\frac{e^{z}}{z}\,dz\ll xh(x)\log T.
\end{align*}

---

To estimate $R_\mu$, we apply $\eqref{perrons}$ to $f(s)=1/\zeta_a(s)$ and $\sigma=1+1/\log x$. Here $$x^\sigma=ex\ll x,\qquad h(x)=1,\\g(\sigma)\leqslant\zeta(\sigma)\ll\frac{1}{\sigma-1}=\log x,$$ so that $|\Delta|\ll(x\log x)/T$. Now we take $\sigma_1=1-C_\sigma/\log T$ from $\eqref{zetaest}$ and use $$\int_\Gamma\frac{x^s\,ds}{s\zeta_a(s)}\,ds=0,$$ where $\Gamma$ is the boundary of $[\sigma_1,\sigma]+i[-T,T]$ (this is the "shift-the-contour" approach mentioned in the beginning). Further, $\eqref{zetaest}$ implies $1/|\zeta_a(s)|\ll(\log x)^2$ $\color{red}{\text{(FIXME)}}$ uniformly w.r.t. $a\leqslant x$ and $s\in\Gamma$.

Hence the "horizontal" integrals are $\ll(\log x)^2/T\int_{\sigma_1}^\sigma x^s\,ds\ll(x\log x)/T$ in absolute value (i.e. the same order as $|\Delta|$), and for the "vertical" integral we have $$\left|\int_{\sigma_1-iT}^{\sigma_1+iT}\frac{x^s\,ds}{s\zeta_a(s)}\right|\ll x^{\sigma_1}(\log x)^2\int_{-T}^T\frac{dt}{|\sigma_1+it|}\ll x^{\sigma_1}(\log x)^3,$$ giving the following estimate for the absolute value of the RHS of $\eqref{perrons}$: $${}\ll\frac{x\log x}{T}+x(\log x)^3\exp\left(-C_\sigma\frac{\log x}{\log T}\right).$$ At $T=\exp\sqrt{C_\sigma\log x}$, this is $\ll x\exp(-C\sqrt{\log x})$ if $C^2<C_\sigma$.

Finally, *there exist positive constants $A,B$ such that $|R_\mu(n,a)|\leqslant A\exp(-B\sqrt{\log n})$*.

For $R_\eta$, things are similar. Here $f(s)=1/\zeta_a(1+s)$, $\sigma=1/\log x$, $h(x)=2/x$, $g(\sigma)\ll\log x$ again, so that $|\Delta|\ll(\log x)/T$ this time; now $\sigma_1=-C_\sigma/\log T$, and $\int_\Gamma=0$ again (since $s=0$ is a removable singularity). Doing all the estimates, we arrive at *the same bound*.

Comment: This is really amazing! I've heard a lot about Perron's formula and it's use for bounding partial sums but I've never been able to pull it off myself.

Comment: Can't one also arrive at the bound for $R_{\eta}$ by applying summation by parts on the $R_{\mu}$ result?

Comment: @MiloMoses: I don't see how. $\mu(ab)/\mu(a)=bR_\mu(b,a)-(b-1)R_\mu(b-1,a)$ results in $$R_\eta(n,a)=R_\mu(n,a)+\sum_{b=1}^{n-1}\frac{R_\mu(b,a)}{b+1},$$ which leads me to nowhere. Do you see anything better?

Comment: When you say $1/|\zeta_a(s)|\ll(\log x)^2$, how do we know the implied constant is independent of $a$? I am using these ideas as part of a paper (if you want to be a co author because of your significant contributions please tell me), and I would like to know so that the paper is fully rigorous.

Comment: @MiloMoses: Looks like I need to fix it (I'll try to, when I get back; surgery in a few hours). We need an uniform upper bound for $\prod_{p\mid a}|1-p^{-s}|$ with $a\leqslant x$ and $s\in\Gamma$...

Comment: If we could show an upper bound of $\prod_{p|a}(1+p^{-1})$, which seems feasible since $\Re(s)$ is approaching 1, this would be enough since $\varphi(a)\cdot \prod_{p|a}(1+p^{-1})<\frac{\pi^2}{6}a$.

Comment: @MiloMoses: We still have to work with $\prod_{p\mid a}(1+p^{-\color{red}{\sigma_1}})$ (*this* is my flaw). An upper bound for $\prod_{p\mid a}(1+p^{-1})\color{red}{\ll\log x}$ can be obtained from [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) (and maybe even an easier way).

Comment: Oh, I forgot that we were working under the condition that $a<x$. I understand my mistake.

Comment: If this is the error, then it shouldn't be any problem to fix. I added in the fix as an edit to end of my answer (the one talking about expected values).

Comment: One more clarifying question: The constant $C$ in Perron's formula is independent of $a_n$, right?

Comment: @MiloMoses: (oops) Yes, it looks like that.

Comment: Also, I finished writing my paper (which uses your work here heavily) and I would like to know if you want me to cite you as a coauthor or not so that I can proceed with publishing guilt free

Comment: @MiloMoses: Well, most of this is a bookshelf matter (an exception maybe is the first part of the linked answer, but even that is trivial enough, and I may well be not good enough in searching - moreover, I won't be surprised if someone finally finds the whole approach to be just a distraction...). So, feel free to run through a crucible of reviews of your paper on your own, marking potential pitfalls with "private communication" ;) (But I'm still "here".)

Comment: Great, thank you! This is my first paper (I'm only 16) and I've been spending a long time on it, and I'm super thankful for your help. Speaking of your help: What are suitable values for $C_{\zeta}$, $C_{\sigma}$, and $T_0$?

Comment: Do you know what values of $C_{\zeta},C_{\sigma},$ and $T_0$ are?

Comment: @MiloMoses: No (basically one has to make the arguments of the section 3 of the Titchmarsh's book *effective*; I didn't dive that deep).